# Flex Module loading stopped working on my dev machine (VerifyError: Error #1014: Class mx.modules::ModuleBase could not be found.)

Tags: apache-flex, module, flash

We have a quiet big flex application compiled with flex 3.4 SDK.

We also have several modules to load after some requirements (some at startup, some later).

Everything is compiled with the same version.

At some point i got this exception on my machine and don't know how to fix it.

```
VerifyError: Error #1014: Class mx.modules::ModuleBase could not be found.

    at flash.display::MovieClip/nextFrame()
    at mx.core::FlexModuleFactory/deferredNextFrame()
    at mx.core::FlexModuleFactory/update()
    at mx.core::FlexModuleFactory/moduleCompleteHandler()
```

I removed and installed already several flashplayer versions, but always the same error.
When we copy the artifacts that are compiled on my machine somewhere and somebody else opens it on his machine it works. So it looks like it is no compilation problem. We have a maven buildprocess, so there shouldn't be any difference anyway.

Comment: +1 for compiling everything in the same Flex version.  Sometimes odd errors magically go away when that happens.  Does the issue only occur on your machine, but nowhere else?  ( Do other test machines have the debug player installed? )

Comment: Could you show your pom?  I'm thinking something isn't being compiled in somewhere.  Also, could you explain where/when the error is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that somehow my flashplayer security settings got lost. Don't know why and how. This meant that i was not allowed to load modules from my local drive(s) anymore. Which is very bad for developing.

You can change this settings easily by going to http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html

Very embarrassing.

Answer (score 0):

Check your module whether it is optimized for some application. To do that go to `Project properties` of your module project, choose the module and press "Edit..." button. Choose "Do not optimize" option.